# Python numpy running sum of repeated trues

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to determine the running sum of true values, but reset to zero when an element is false.

For example, the input:

```
np.array([0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1])
```

would result in:

```
np.array([0,0,1,2,3,4,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,2])
```

I prefer a pure numpy solution

Comment: Your example works directly with the linked answer; you could replace `(a == 1)` with `(a != 0)` to support all truelike values.

Comment: @DSM Sorry for the duplicate.  I didn't find that question when I searched.  Thank you for the response